# Set Advanced permissions for list programatically in add-in

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have started development in Visual Studio.

I need help on how to programatically set Advanced permissions for a SharePoint list, specifically the "Create items and edit items that were created by the user​​​" setting

Answer (score 1):

Try it as below:

```
var customList = web.GetListByTitle("Documenten");

// Change the advanced settings
//1— All users have Read access to all items.
//2— Users have Read access only to items that they create.

customList.ReadSecurity = 2;

//1— Write all items.
//2— Write only my items.
//4— Write no items (read-only list).

customList.WriteSecurity = 2;

customList.Update()
context.Load(customList);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Ensure that you have the latest version of CSOM or atleast August 2016 CSOM dll.

[SharePoint CSOM version released for SharePoint Online - August 2016](https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-august-2016-updated)

Comment: Im developing sharepoint online add-ins especially lists for now and could u help me with? Is this solution for sharepoint online? Where i need put this code provided by you? Thanks

Comment: Yes its a solution for SharePoint online. How are you provisioning lists ? Are you using CSOM/JSOM/REST api ?

Comment: Hi thanks for fast response. Im using CSOM. I wrote this code to Remote Event Receiver, into function public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent, Is it right? Compilation is okay, but doesnt work.